# Seemingly identical primitive values aren't equal

Tags: c#, casting, equality, primitive

A strange case popped up. Two properties of two objects are being cast to the same primitive type and (seemingly) have the same value. However, the equality comparer returns `false`. If we use the `Equals` method (or other means of comparing the two values), then we get the correct result.

Even stranger, actually placing the result of the cast into a new variable also seems to works.

Below is a VERY simplified code example and and it will **NOT** yield the same results when copied and compiled. It's just used to illustrate the general setting where the problem occurs.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v1 = new Object1 { SomeValue = (short)-1d };

        var invalidResult = (int)v1.SomeValue == (int)SomeEnum.Value1;     //for some reason this returns false
        var validResult = ((int)v1.SomeValue).CompareTo((int)SomeEnum.Value1) == 0;    //this works
        var extraValidResult = ((int)v1.SomeValue).Equals((int)SomeEnum.Value1);
        var cast1 = (int)v1.SomeValue;
        var cast2 = (int)SomeEnum.Value1;
        var otherValidResult = cast1 == cast2;                          //this also works
    }
}

public class Object1
{
    public short SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public enum SomeEnum : short
{
    Value1 = -1,
    Value2 = 0,
    Value3 = 1
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the VS watch window as proof of what we're seeing:

[image: Proof]

I know sometimes VS can show invalid values in the "watches" window, however the effects aren't limited to that window and a case actually fails an `if` check where it should not in one of our tests. AFAIK there's no trickery in the code (like overriding `==` or `Equals`).

What could possibly be happening here?

(We've obviously "fixed" the issue using the `CompareTo` method, but we're all still scratching our heads wondering what exactly had happened...)

EDIT:
I realize the code example above is... a tad bit useless. However posting the actual code in question might prove to be very difficult; there's a lot of it. Finally, the "live" values of some objects are populated from a SQL server (using Entity Framework), which complicates sharing of the code even further. I'm happy to try and answer any additional questions to try and narrow down the issue, but sharing of the FULL code is, unfortunately, not possible (a specific block of it is possible, but it won't compile for obvious reasons). The example code was provided to show how strange the issue is.

EDIT 2:
Sorry for the delay. Here's the particular method in question:

```
public bool IsLocalizationBlockedByMagPElem(int localizationId)
{
    IEnumerable<MagPElem> magPElems = MagPElemRepository.GetByLocalizationIdAndStatusesOrderedByIdDescThenSubLpAsc(localizationId, DocumentStatus.InBuffer, DocumentStatus.InBufferReedition);

    if (magPElems.Count() != 0)
    {
        var magPElem = magPElems.First();
        //this commented out code did not return the expected value due to the strange comparison issue
        //return (magPElem.MaP_GIDTyp == (int)ExternalSystemType.PM_GIDTyp || (magPElem.MaP_GIDTyp == (int)ExternalSystemType.MP_GIDTyp && magPElem.MaP_SubGIDLp == (short)LocalizationDirection.Destination));
        //to avoid the issue CompareTo is being used, but Equals would work just as well
        return (magPElem.MaP_GIDTyp == (int)ExternalSystemType.PM_GIDTyp || (magPElem.MaP_GIDTyp == (int)ExternalSystemType.MP_GIDTyp && magPElem.MaP_SubGIDLp.CompareTo((short)LocalizationDirection.Destination) == 0));
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've also updated the proof screenshot to encompass more of the screen. In the screenshot there are some minor discrepancies with the above code as we were testing to see what's going on (like trying out different casts or assigning the cast result to a variable). But the gist of the problem is there.

Comment: invalidResult is true for me...visual studio 2015, target framework 4.5.2  (ETA: missed comment that the code snipped won't produce same results)

Comment: "and it will NOT yield the same results when copied and compiled" - then the difference is somewhere in the difference between what you've posted, and your real code. So that narrows it down. But... this is going to be very hard to answer without actual code that reproduces the error. It *looks* like it should work, I'll give you that - but: the VS watch window is not very reliable as an oracle of these things. But yeah, the fact that it is -1 as an int, -1 as an int, and false: is very odd

Comment: @NDJ the OP did indicate that the code in the question doesn't actually demonstrate the same issue, and is illustrative of the setup only

Comment: It's better to post your real code, since simplified setup is useless anyway.

Comment: @MarcGravell oops, missed that

Comment: random thought: in the real code, do either of those properties have side-effects? i.e. does `LocalizationDirection.Destination` **keep** reliably returning that -1 value over and over and over? Likewise `mapPElem.MaP_SubGIDLp`? If the properties have side-effects: all bets are off...

Comment: if we accept the report at face value and assume that there's nothing like "side effects" in play, then with first line `var invalidResult = (int)v1.SomeValue == (int)v2.EnumValue;` (fails) and the last 3 lines `var cast1 = (int)v1.SomeValue;`, `var cast2 = (int)v2.EnumValue;` and `var otherValidResult = cast1 == cast2;` (works as expected): I would be *open to the idea* that there's a compiler bug at play here ... *once* all other causes have been ruled out first :) The key, unfortunately, is getting a reliable repro. But for curiosity: what compiler version are you using currently?

Comment: Maybe analysing IL code differences between your actual code and this snippet could show you the differences

Comment: But you don't need to post full real code, just a line where it fails (and several surrounding lines).

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, the properties return the same values reliably. As I described, using `Equals` works - if the values were unreliable then I'd expect that would also fail (at least some of the time).

Comment: @Evk I will provide those few lines shortly.

Comment: @MarcGravell The .NET version at the moment is 4.5.2, and we're using VS 2017 (not 100% sure what the actual compiler version for that is). The code is being tested and developed on a colleagues system, which means there's some back and forth when I try to get info for this SO case. ;)

Comment: Visual studio 2017, .net 4.6.2 and the value assigned to invalidResult is true but the expression `(int)v1.SomeValue == (int)SomeEnum.Value1` shows as false in the watch window.

Comment: @SeanReid Very true! I can confirm that. Is it possible that tests are somehow reliant on the same (or similar) mechanisms that are powering the watch window?

Comment: In the watch window, I get  `v1.SomeValue == -1` as `false`. If I change the type of `SomeValue` to `int`, it works as expected.

Comment: Also, only negative numbers are affected and `v1.SomeValue == -1d` is `true`.